# How to flash plcc 32 chip with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

The specific model is the [W39V080FA](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/181469/WINBOND/W39V080FA.html) and I'm quite a noob when it comes to flashing.

I've already prepared the circuit to divide the voltage and use a proper 3.3V.

I have an plcc to dip adapter, but I really don't know how to wire each pin, really need some tips. Thanks.

Comment: you have to determine which signals are required to write data to the chip ... then you have to write a program that generates those signals ... determining the required signals is in no way related to the Arduino ... your question would be related to the arduino only when you know which signals to generate, but have problems generating those signals with the arduino

Comment: it sounds like a lot of work, but thankfully there's a great project called Flashrom that get rid of those assignments, and their official docs point that this chip is supported. My barrier is building the circuit (assigning the pins to Arduino). Also, thanks for your response

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, adding the link to the mentioned project. Also add _what_ specifically stops you from assigning pins. You don't want us to guess, do you?